# Optimizing the LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, optimization

I am using EFF with MySql database, where I have 3 different tables(say users, groceries, usersItems). and the situation is-

1. UsersItems has list of users involved in the groceries purchase. 
   Column `UserInvolved`is a foreign key to `users.UserID` and 
   Column `GroceryID` is a foreign key to `groceries.ItemID`.
2. groceries has the list of groceries been purchased.
3. users have the list of user details.(only **Name** is concerned about the table)

What I want to achieve is that, 
*A List of groceries is chosen frm the `groceries`* table.
Based on this list, I have to get the list of users involved in the purchase of these list from the table `usersItems`. Finally I have to get the names of these users from the `users` table and Show these names as a `;` semicolon separated.

Here's the association between the tables-
[image]

and here's what I had tried to achieve this by Linq

```
var gList = entities.groceries.Select(item => item.ItemID);
var uInvolved = entities.usersitems.Where(item => gList.Contains(item.GroceryId)).Select(u => u.userInvolved);
var usrs = string.Join(";", entities.users.Where(us => uInvolved.Contains(us.UserID)).Select(name => name.FullName));
```

By using these linq, I am getting the result what I want, but as you can see this is not much optimized. Overall, I want to shorten/Optimize these queries and I am very much confused, where I am getting wrong.
Also, I had tried to achieve this result as a  `View` directly from the database, but still I couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = entities.users.Where(u=> u.useritems.SelectMany(ui=> ui.groceries).Any()).Select(u=> u.FullName);
```

This is using the navigation properties ... if you get a foreignkey relation ... your navigation properties maybe named different though

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is a `many-to-many relationship` using a `bridge table`. I suggest checking this tutorial at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMQwORSTGX4.

Basically what you need to do is to remove the `IndexNum` column. Then you should re-generate your model and you will be able to check for:

```
var groceries = user.Groceries;
var users = gorcery.Users;
```